# Strange lifecycle behavior in my Screen Saver App

Tags: android, lifecycle, screensaver

I just developed a screen saver app and I found a strange behavior in its lifecycle.
My work flow is like this:

1. start my `RegisterService`, where I call `registerReceiver` method to register a `BroadcastReceiver`, which can receive `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`.

2.In the `onReceive` method of this `BroadcastReceiver`, I start an activity as the screensaver.

3.In the activity, I write `Log.i()` statement to track its running.

My question is:

When the screen times out, or when I press the POWER key, the screen turns off, and the system will send ACTION_SCREEN_OFF message. As I expect, my receiver starts the screen saver activity. However, I find this Activity calls `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()`, `onResume()` sequentially according to the output in logcat.

**It seems as if some a activity comes at front of my screensaver and finishes immediately, so my screensaver calls `onPause()` and then `onResume()`**.
[image]

Any idea? This problem handicaps me in programming, please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you something very easy that might work for you, if you do not want the pause behavior why don't you try to Override the method `onPause()` and just do nothing :P **don't call `super.onPause()`** and that will terminate the behavior of it.

Other thing that might work for you, declare a static variable, add 1 on the "onResume()" method and return to "0" when "onStop()" is called. now just evaluate when the "onResume()" is called and if the variable is "0" then is the first time, anything else do nothing.

I hope this helps cause there is no much information on your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Well based on a brief study of the [PowerManagerService.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/PowerManagerService.java) source code, when it's time to turn the screen off, the system initiates an animation (look at line 2183 for the class source) to do that. That means that your activity will pause and then will resume after the animation has ended.

I cannot be 100% sure for this, since I haven't tested it in my environment but this is the only logical explanation I found for your situation.

Hope this helps...