# WakeLock Mechanism

Tags: android

In my app there is a Broadcast Receiver which is called by an alarm with RTC_WAKEUP at specific times. This receiver first acquire a partial lock so it doesn't terminate and then checks a condition and if it's true start an activity which turns the phone completely on by a acquiring a full lock and unlocking keyguard.

After a little test and trial I found out lifecycle of Broadcast receiver ends before starting the activity, and as soon as it ends the partial lock is released.

- So I wonder if the device is sleep, would the activity get started so
  it can acquire full lock?
- Or as soon as the broadcast receiver ends the device goes back to
  sleep and start of activity is postponed to when it wakes again?

Comment: I think your app is designed to start an Activity at a specific time, like the native alarm Activity, isn't it?

Comment: @Huang Yes, it's a reminder but I want to check simple offline condition before starting the activity. Is there any source code like alarm activity available to check? I couldn't find one. I want to see if I do things right.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to start an Activity in a BroadcastReceiver, don't forget to add the flag: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

   ```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
     if (check condition) {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setClass(context,THE_ACTIVTY_YOU_WANT_TO_START.class);
       context.startActivity(intent);
           } 

    }
   ```
2. use the FULL_WAKE_LOCK to force to turn the screen on, add the codes below in the onCreate() method to do so.

   ```
   pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

       km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
       kl = km.newKeyguardLock("info");
       wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
               | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
               | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "info");
       kl.disableKeyguard();
   ```

Comment: This is what I have done, my question is if the activity starts at all or not?

Comment: Somewhere I read disabling keyguard must be done before power wakelock and somewhere else the opposite, which one is better?

Comment: @Ali I have written an Alarm like activity, and I used the code above( calling disableKeyguard() first in onCreate() and then wl.acquire() in the onResume()). It works fine for me.

Comment: @Ali I didn't read the source code the the powermanager of AOSP and I gave my answer just based on my practice. I can't answer the mechanism behind it...

Comment: There is an strange behavior about keyguard unlocking. After unlock the onresume is first called then onpause is called, then again onresume is called. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: @Ali Yes, I've met the same problem. and I even asked such a question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715653/strange-lifecycle-behavior-in-my-screen-saver-app One answer say that it results from a transition animation when the device gets unlocked, but I'm not sure... I didn't study the source code. But in general, that won't hurt you if your app is just a reminder. call wl.acquire in onResume() and wl.release() in onPause()

Comment: There is another bug there, I finish activity when audio ends, and there is a conflict between finish and release lock which says Program stopped unexpectedly, even no exception!?

Answer (score 0):

While looking through the GCM manual I found the following chapter:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#handling_intents

I think you have to aquire the WakeLock while still being in BroadcastReceiver#onReceive. They use a static WakeLock in their IntentService.